# HTML5 h264 Live streaming video

Tags: html, streaming, h.264

I currently have a working H264 + AAC live stream server, but uses flv as a container and RTMP/HLS as a protocol (nginx back-end), which means that client-side I can only use flash based players, such as jwplayer or video.js.

What can I change in my 'chain' to allow HTML5 streaming? HLS works on mobile but not on desktop.
I manage all the system (meaning I can use another container, back end, protocol, etc).

Just to clarify: I do not want to stream static files, I want to stream live video

Also, I do not need controls(play/pause/ff/rewind)

Edit: It seems that rtsp->webRTC might be doable. I'm looking into it atm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a player that check both protocols (RTMP + HLS), for Flash/Desktop use RTMP, and HLS for mobile (iOS / Android > 4.4). 
For example Jwplayer or OSMF can play Hls protocol for Flash players, so choosing the right player you can use and configure only Hls protocol.

Html5 on desktop needs progressive download and more more than only one video codecs (like mp4 and ogg).

Comment: I want to do HTML5 playback on desktop, not flash playback

Comment: Html5 on desktop needs progressive download and more video codecs (like mp4 and ogg). more infos: http://www.overdigital.com/2013/10/28/html5-video-guide-need-know-2014/